# How can I list and manage multiple handles I created for my channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I added a second handle to my YouTube channel this morning.

I can access my channel with either handle, but, if I navigate to [youtube.com/handle](https://www.youtube.com/handle) , I don't see the new handle, I only see the original one.

I don't know how if multiple handles are supported, and how many, or if my new handle will replace the original one within a few days at which time the original handle will no longer work.

I'm also not clear if it's possible to transfer a handle to a different channel.

My research returned conflicting information:

> **Each channel can only have one handle**. You'll see handles in places like comments, mentions, and in Shorts. Your handle will show in more places over time. You can also use your handle outside of YouTube to promote your channel. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11585688

> **Creating a second channel is a great way to keep your content organized**.
> https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/video/hub/guides/how-to-start-second-youtube-channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update from OP

OP confirmed the handle change they initiated Nov. 17, 2022 became permanent Dec. 1, 2022. This is in line with the YouTube documentation below which notes a 14-day window during which users can undo the change.

#### Changing a Youtube Handle

[Handles Overview > Change Handle](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11585688#change_handle)

> If you change your handle, we hold your previous handle for 14 days in case you’d like to switch back. During this 14-day period, your former handle URL and your updated URL will both work. After 14 days, the handle will become available for other users to select as their handle.

If you **changed** your handle that applies to you.

#### Unique Channels have Unique Handles

> [Handles Overview](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11585688)
> All channels will have an associated handle that can be used to find and interact with other users– both creators and viewers. Your handle will also automatically become the new YouTube URL for your channel that will make it easy for people to discover you. For example, youtube.com/@youtubecreators. You can use this URL to direct people to your channel when they’re not on YouTube. Each channel can only have one handle.
>
> Handle URL
> Example: [youtube.com/@youtubecreators](HTTPS://youtube.com/@youtubecreators)
>
> A handle URL is created automatically whenever you choose or change your handle as a channel owner. The end of the URL starts with an “@” symbol and includes your chosen handle. Any custom URLs you may already have will continue to work.

If you use **2 handles** attached to **2 distinct channels** then that applies to you.

#### Channel URLs

> [Understand your YouTube channel's URLs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214)
> Your channel can have more than one URL that directs your audience to your channel homepage. These URLs can look different from one another, but each URL can point your audience to the same place - your channel. Handle URLs, custom URLs, and legacy username URLs are all forms of personalized URLs. You can view all URLs associated with your channel at [youtube.com/handle](http://youtube.com/handle)